# Confusion about articles and quantifiers: "a pair of scissors" vs "any scissors" vs "scissors"

Tags: articles, idioms, questions

Which of the following questions, if any, would work (or you would normally say) when asking a colleague or a class-mate? I am asking them for the purpose of using/borrowing the items if they have them.

1.Do you have any scissors / any glue/ any scotch tape/ any needle and thread?

2.Do you have a pair of scissors / a glue/ a scotch tape / a needle and a thread?

3.Do you have scissors / glue/ scotch tape / needle and thread?

4.Or anything else I have not thought of?

## ***Re­gional Note***

By writing "/", I did not want to repeat the same question 4 times for each word.
So, "Do you have any scissors / any glue/ any scotch tape/ any needle and thread?" means "Do you have any scissors?", "Do you have any glue?", "Do you have any scotch tape?" and "Do you have any needle and thread?".

Comment: Yes, "do you have **some** glue / tape," but not for the other items, although with *scissors* (a plural word) it is arguable.

Comment: So, would you normally say "Do you have some glue/tape?"?

Comment: Are you asking them for the purpose of borrowing/using the items if they have them? I would phrase things differently if you are asking instead whether they have the items they need to perform some task.

Comment: Yes,I am asking them if I could use them

Comment: I was answering "4. Anything else?" Asking for "any" is quite acceptable, except "Do a you have **a** needle and thread?" because it is singular.

Comment: @Weather Vane Thanks for your comments. So, how would you ask your colleague if you needed to sew something and you didn't have any tools? Would you say "Can I  borrow needle and thread if you have them?"?

Comment: It should have the article **a**.

Comment: @Weather Vane like this? "Can I borrow a needle and a thread if you have them?

Comment: Can I borrow a needle and (some) thread?

Comment: @Weather Vane Thanks. You said "do you have some scissors" might work. So, what do you normally say in that situation? "Mate can I borrow some scissors?" or anything else ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first of all, there's two different questions here.  One is what you *can* say, and the other is what's the *best* way to say it.

The answer to what you actually can and can't say is different for several of the different items in your examples, and the reason for this is that some of the things you're referring to are *countable nouns* and some of them are *uncountable nouns*.

*Countable nouns* are what we normally deal with, for example, a pen:  You can have "one pen", "two pens", "many pens", etc.

The *countable nouns* in your examples are:

- pair of scissors
- needle

*Uncountable nouns* do not generally have a number.  This is often used for liquids and things where there's no obvious division between "items".  An example of this from your question is "glue".  You don't generally say you have "one glue" or "two glues".  Instead, "glue" is just a substance you can have some amount of, but not a specific number of ("a little glue", "a lot of glue", etc).

The *uncountable nouns* in your examples are:

- scissors
- glue
- tape
- thread

(Note: "thread" can sometimes be countable, if you're talking about individual threads, but in the context we're dealing with here (i.e. thread on a spool of indeterminate length), it, like tape, is in an uncountable form)

Now, you might have noticed something here:  "scissors" can be either a countable noun or an uncountable noun depending on whether we refer to it as "a pair of scissors" or just "scissors".

So, for countable nouns, you can say any of the following:

- a/an *(noun)*
- some *(plural-noun)*
- any *(plural-noun)*

Note that when using "any" or "some" you need to use the plural of the noun (e.g. "pairs of scissors", "needles").  However, uncountable nouns don't have plurals, so they don't change.  Uncountable nouns also can't use the indefinite article ("a"/"an").

For uncountable nouns you can say the following:

- *(noun)*
- some *(noun)*
- any *(noun)*

So, therefore, you can say any of the following:

> Do you have some/any scissors? *(uncountable "scissors")*
>   Do you have some/any glue? *(uncountable)*
>   Do you have some/any scotch tape? *(uncountable)*
>   Do you have some/any needles? *(countable, so plural)*
>   Do you have a pair of scissors? *(countable)*
>   Do you have scissors? *(uncountable)*
>   Do you have glue? *(uncountable)*
>   Do you have scotch tape? *(uncountable)*

The following, however, are wrong:

> Do you have a glue? *(wrong, because uncountables can't use "a")*
>   Do you have a scotch tape? *(wrong, because uncountables can't use "a")*

Now, you may have noticed that "needle" is countable, but "thread" is uncountable.  So what do we do about "needle and thread"?  There's two ways this can be handled.  We can either consider them as two separate things we're asking for, and handle each one appropriately, or we can consider "needle and thread" to be one item (which is how many people often think of it).  If it's a singular item, then "needle and thread" is actually countable, because it's got a countable element in it ("needle"), but it's also something that's not often actually counted (you don't generally say you have multiple "needles and thread").  This is partly because in order to do that, you need to use the plural form of "needle", but there is no plural form of "thread" (since it's uncountable), so you end up with something that looks like it's mixing plural and singular forms, which is going to sound odd to most people's ears.  So in general, even though they technically could, people just don't tend to do that very much.

So you can say:

> Do you have a needle and thread? *(singular countable is fine)*
>   Do you have a needle and some thread? *(two separate items, one countable, one uncountable)*

But the following, while technically ok, sounds a bit strange:

> Do you have some/any needles and thread?  *(technically ok, but sounds odd)*

And the following is just wrong:

> Do you have a needle and a thread? *("thread" is uncountable, so can't use "a")*
>   Do you have needle and thread? *(wrong, because "needle" must use "a")*

---

So that takes care of what you are actually allowed (grammatically) to say, on to the question of what "sounds right" when asking somebody to use something.

Pretty much any of the following are perfectly natural requests, and sound fine when asking to use something:

> Do you have any *(countable/uncountable somethings)*?
>   Do you have a *(countable something)*?
>   Do you have *(uncountable something)*?
>   Do you have some *(uncountable something)*?

You can also use "some" with countables:

> Do you have some *(countable somethings)*?

but if you do it will generally imply that you want to use more than one of them, instead of just one (i.e. if you say "do you have some needles", people will assume you want to use more than one needle, and might respond with something like "no, I only have one").

One note to make here, though regarding "scissors" vs. "pair of scissors", is that it's uncommon to hear things like "any pairs of scissors".  People will generally opt instead for just saying "any scissors".  Even though it's technically countable, usually the only time "pair of scissors" is actually used is as a singular item ("a pair of scissors").

Note that if you instead want to say something like "Can I have/use" instead of "Do you have", then the above are also fine except that you generally don't want to use "any"

> Can I have any *(something)*?  *<-- careful!*

The reason for this is because, unlike the other forms, the use of "any" here often implies that they are not currently letting you have any of something (they are keeping it all to themselves).

So in summary, the following are all fine and natural:

> Do you have any scissors?
>   Do you have any glue?
>   Do you have any scotch tape?
>   Do you have some scissors?
>   Do you have some glue?
>   Do you have some scotch tape?
>   Do you have a pair of scissors?
>   Do you have scissors?
>   Do you have glue?
>   Do you have scotch tape?
>   Do you have a needle and thread?
>   Do you have a needle and some thread?

Comment: Thank you so much!